# Create dbpedia subset and host it locally

Tags: sparql, rdf, dbpedia

I need to create and locally host a subset of dbpedia data which should only contain geographical information. Like of countries, rivers etc.

I found resources for [setting up a Linked Data mirror from RDF dumps](https://joernhees.de/blog/2015/11/23/setting-up-a-linked-data-mirror-from-rdf-dumps-dbpedia-2015-04-freebase-wikidata-linkedgeodata-with-virtuso-7-2-1-and-docker-optional/), but I cannot understand how to subset the data.

Comment: This question is too broad (How would you define "geographical information" to produce such a subset? Do birthplaces count, so (some) people should be included?) to be well answered in its current form, and is likely not [appropriate for SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) anyway…

Comment: SPARQL CONSTRUCT on the classes that you consider to be relevant could work. And then with possible paths incoming and outgoing of instances of those types.

Comment: I only need country information like capitals, rivers and cities.

Comment: It is possible to only load data of country class in dbpedia ontology? http://dbpedia.org/ontology/country

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a SPARQL queries and dumped the results in RDF format, which later I was able to host locally by loading the data on a virtuoso server. For my use-case that was enough.